# Depth first iterative deepening algorithm to print a binary tree breadth first

Tags: python, data-structures, recursion

I'm not a programmer but as part of a personal project of mine I'm keen to understand if there is a recursive solution to being able to print a binary tree breadth first, level order? I understand an iterative depth first algorithm could be used?

```
#Helper method
def getChildren(node):
    children=[]
    hasLeft = node.left is not None
    hasRight = node.right is not None
    if not hasLeft and not hasRight:
        return []
    if hasLeft:
        children.append(node.left)
    if hasRight:
        children.append(node.right)
    return children

def DLS(node, depth):
    """Depth Limited Search"""
    if (depth == 0):
        return node
    elif (depth > 0):
        print node.value,
        children = getChildren(node)
        for child in children:
            DLS(child, depth-1)
    else:
        return False
```

For the following binary tree:
`(1)3

(2)2 (3)1

(4)1 (5)1 (6)1 (7)0

(8)1 (9)0`

I'm getting this traversal output:
`(1)3 (2)2 (4)1 (8)1 (9)0 (5)1 (3)1 (6)1 (7)0 None`

Which is not level order but pre-order depth first.

Do I have to iterate the depth to the `DLS` function? How would I implement for a level order printout of the binary tree?

Many thanks
Alex

Comment: Hi @andrewcooke I did think I'm asking around the same question, over three of my questions; but was keen to keep asking on this subject as I've been thinking through some of the ideas and feedback. I didn't really want to delete my questions as I want to refer back over the responses give as I'm learning. Is there any way of archiving my old questions, so I can refer back? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of data structures, the difference between depth-first and breadth-first is that depth-first uses a stack and breadth-first uses a queue.

In depth-first, the idea is "deal with the consequences of the last thing you dealt with". So with a stack you always pop the last node that was pushed, and you get the right behaviour.

In breadth-first, the idea is "first deal with all the consequences of the chosen node, then move on". So you first find out the consequences (and store them), and only then you start dealing with them in the order you found them. The simplest data structure to support this is a queue.

The problem is that recursion uses a stack (the call stack). So you don't see the data structure, but it's actually there. Because there is no (simple) way of queuing calls, you can't translate a breadth-first search to code without using an explicit queue.

If you need information about breadth-first implementation with a queue, I suggest you check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: Hi @OmriBarel I have implemented a Breadth-first search using a Queue. I think on balance I should stick with this function then. Thanks Alex